# How to show that $\Bbb R$ with the topology generated by $\{(a,b):a,b\in\Bbb R\}\cup\{(a,b)\cap\Bbb Q:a,b\in\Bbb R\}$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology

I'm sorry that I'm not good at English. My question is

> Let $B = \{(a,b) : a,b \in \mathbb{R} \} \cup \{ (a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q} : a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is basis of $\tau$. Then $(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ is connected?

I think $(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ is connected.

Because form of open set is finite intersection of $(a,b)$ or $(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$, arbitrary union of $(a,b)$ or $(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Form of closed set is finite union of $[a,b]$ or $[a,b]-\mathbb{Q}$ or arbitrary intersection of $[a,b]$ or $[a,b]-\mathbb{Q}$.

So closed and open set is either $\emptyset$ or $\mathbb{R}$. But i don't know how to show that this. Help me. Thank you for reading what i wrote .

Comment: Why do you mention finite intersections? $B$ is given to be a basis, not a sub-basis ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clopen sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628081/clopen-sets-in-mathbbrn)

Comment: @Patrick Stevens I don't know that what you mean

Answer (score 2):

Note the following property fo $\tau$:

> If $O$ is open and $x\in O$, then there exist $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<x<b$ and $(a,b)\cap\Bbb Q\subseteq O$.

Assume $\Bbb R=U\cup V$ with $U,V$ non-empty open. We have to show that $U\cap V\ne\emptyset$.

Pick $u\in U$, $v\in V$. Wlog. $u<v$.
Let $$w=\inf\{\,x\in \Bbb R\mid x>u\land \exists y>x\colon (x,y)\cap\Bbb Q\subseteq V\,\}$$
(so that $u\le a<v$). 
If $w=u$, we are done.
So we can assume $w>u$.
If $w\in V$, then by the property in the first paragraph, $(a,b)\cap \Bbb Q\subseteq V$ for some $a<w<b$. If $a>u$, we arrive at a contradiction with the definition of $w$ as an infimum. And if $a\le u$, then also $(\frac{u+w}2,b)\cap \Bbb Q\subseteq V$ and we arrive at the same contradiction.

We conclude that $w\notin V$, hence $w\in U$.
Therefore, there exist $a<w<b$ with $(a,b)\cap \Bbb Q\subseteq U$. By definition of infimum, there exist $x,y$ with $u<x<b$ and $(x,y)\cap \Bbb Q\subseteq V$. Then the non-empty set $(x,\min\{y,b\})\cap \Bbb Q$ is $\subseteq U\cap V$. $\square$

Comment: so that $u\leq w<v$

Comment: I have a question of propety. If $x$ is irreducible, then there exists $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x \in (a,b) \subset O$

Comment: @iDeal I think you mean irrational and yes that is true. If $O$ is open and $x \in O$ then $x$ is contained in a basis set contained in $O$. But $x$ can only belong to open intervals $(a,b)$ with $a < x < b$. We can't have $x \in (a, b) \cap \mathbf{Q}$.